# Which version of Fiddler should I use for a .NET 3.5 client app connecting to a .NET 4.5 server app?

Tags: .net-3.5, compact-framework, .net-4.5, windows-ce, fiddler

I have used Wireshark and RawCap and who knows what else to try to determine why I can never get my .NET 3.5 Compact Framework / Windows CE app (running on a handheld device) to connect with my .NET 4.5 "regular" server app running on my PC (or elsewhere on the network).

I thought I would give Fiddler a try, but the [download page](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) shows two versions, one for .NET 4, and one for .NET 2. Since one of my apps is pre-.NET 4, and the other is post-.NET 4, which download should I use?

Am I the only one who, whenever he sees the word "Fiddler," thinks of the scene in Roots where the cat by that moniker croaks, and Kunte Kinte yells out, "Fiddler!" (although it sounds more like, "Fiddle-UH!!!")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter.  It's just a tool you'll run on your desktop to look at network traffic.  The end point clients, whether a CF app, a CE device, a browser, a Linux appliance or whatever is irrelevant.

Generally you'd likely choose the .NET 2.0 version if your PC was running something that only had .NET 2.0 on it, like XP, or if you couldn't install .NET 4 for whatever reason.